# In Google Dataproc templates GCS to Bigtable dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

In GCS To Bigtable template (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-templates/tree/main/python/dataproc_templates/gcs#gcs-to-bigtable) It lists hbase-spark-protocol-shaded.jar and hbase-spark.jar as dependencies.

I receive the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:79)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 43 more
```

If add the following to my python job

```
print(f"/usr/lib/spark/external/: {os.listdir('/usr/lib/spark/external/')}", flush=True)
```

It shows

```
/usr/lib/spark/external/: ['spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10.jar', 'spark-avro_2.12-3.3.1.jar', 'spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.1.jar', 'spark-sql-kafka-0-10.jar', 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly.jar', 'spark-avro.jar', 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.3.1.jar', 'spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.1.jar']
```

Which does not have the `hbase-spark-protocol-shaded.jar` nor the `hbase-spark.jar`.

Where do I retrieve the correct versions from?

I'm using the `--version=1.1` flag in the `gcloud` command for the GCP Spark runtime (ref: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/versions/spark-runtime-versions#spark_runtime_version_11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hbase-spark.jar` and `hbase-spark-protocol-shaded.jar` will be included in the runtime 1.1 in next subminor runtime version (1.1.4) that should roll out by Feb 24.

In meantime, as a workaround you can use runtime 1.0.